# Google-like search query tokenization & string splitting

Tags: c#, search, tokenize

I'm looking to tokenize a search query similar to how Google does it.  For instance, if I have the following search query:

```
the quick "brown fox" jumps over the "lazy dog"
```

I would like to have a string array with the following tokens:

```
the
quick
brown fox
jumps
over
the
lazy dog
```

As you can see, the tokens preserve the spaces with in double quotes.

I'm looking for some examples of how I could do this in C#, preferably not using regular expressions, however if that makes the most sense and would be the most performant, then so be it.

Also I would like to know how I could extend this to handle other special characters, for example, putting a - in front of a term to force exclusion from a search query and so on.

Comment: In your syntax, can the double quote character (") be used anywhere else besides indicating a multi-word token?

Comment: For my purposes, no it cannot.

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14655023/split-a-string-that-has-white-spaces-unless-they-are-enclosed-within-quotes is similar for this question. 
(Though I was seeking a mechanism that supports "filetype:pdf" like queries. )

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So far, this looks like a good candidate for RegEx's.  If it gets significantly more complicated, then a more complex tokenizing scheme may be necessary, but your should avoid that route unless necessary as it is significantly more work. (on the other hand, for complex schemas, regex quickly turns into a dog and should likewise be avoided).

This regex should solve your problem:

```
("[^"]+"|\w+)\s*
```

Here is a C# example of its usage:

```
string data = "the quick \"brown fox\" jumps over the \"lazy dog\"";
string pattern = @"(""[^""]+""|\w+)\s*";

MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(data, pattern);
foreach(Match m in mc)
{
    string group = m.Groups[0].Value;
}
```

The real benefit of this method is it can be easily extened to include your "-" requirement like so:

```
string data = "the quick \"brown fox\" jumps over " +
              "the \"lazy dog\" -\"lazy cat\" -energetic";
string pattern = @"(-""[^""]+""|""[^""]+""|-\w+|\w+)\s*";

MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(data, pattern);
foreach(Match m in mc)
{
    string group = m.Groups[0].Value;
}
```

Now I hate reading Regex's as much as the next guy, but if you split it up, this one is quite easy to read:

```
(
-"[^"]+"
|
"[^"]+"
|
-\w+
|
\w+
)\s*
```

**Explanation**

1. If possible match a minus sign, followed by a " followed by everything until the next "
2. Otherwise match a " followed by everything until the next "
3. Otherwise match a - followed by any word characters
4. Otherwise match as many word characters as you can
5. Put the result in a group
6. Swallow up any following space characters

Answer (score 2):

I was just trying to figure out how to do this a few days ago.  I ended up using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser which did exactly what I wanted (just set HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes to true). Sure it looks somewhat odd to have "Microsoft.VisualBasic" in a C# program, but it works, and as far as I can tell it is part of the .NET framework.

To get my string into a stream for the TextFieldParser, I used "new MemoryStream(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(stringvar))".  Not sure if this is the best way to do it.

Edit: I don't think this would handle your "-" requirement, so maybe the RegEx solution is better

Comment: the TextFieldParser has an overload that accepts strings, you do not need to make a MemoryStream.

Answer (score 1):

Go char by char to the string like this: (sort of pseudo code)

```
array words = {} // empty array
string word = "" // empty word
bool in_quotes = false
for char c in search string:
    if in_quotes:
        if c is '"':
            append word to words
            word = "" // empty word
            in_quotes = false
        else:
            append c to word
   else if c is '"':
        in_quotes = true
   else if c is ' ': // space
       if not empty word:
           append word to words
           word = "" // empty word
   else:
        append c to word

// Rest
if not empty word:
    append word to words
```

Comment: I think this is roughly about what I was thinking if regex isn't sufficient.

However, I **very strongly** recommend that word not be a string. You're going to allocate strings like mad due to immutability of strings. Better to make word a string builder or even just an array of chars.

Comment: You are right. But this was pseudo code. It is about the principle.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a Java solution to this problem and came up with a solution using @Michael La Voie's. Thought I would share it here despite the question being asked for in C#. Hope that's okay.

```
public static final List<String> convertQueryToWords(String q) {
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\"[^\"]+\"|\\w+)\\s*");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(q);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        MatchResult result = matcher.toMatchResult();
        if (result != null && result.group() != null) {
            if (result.group().contains("\"")) {
                words.add(result.group().trim().replaceAll("\"", "").trim());
            } else {
                words.add(result.group().trim());
            }
        }
    }
    return words;
}
```