# Fetch words in a sentence

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have string - `My name is "foo bar" I live in New York`

Now I want to split it to an array but words in double quotes should be considered as one.

I have tried `input.split(' ')` but need some help how to handle strings inside double quotes.

I want output as `['My', 'name', 'is', '"foo bar"', 'I', 'live', 'in', 'New', 'York']`

Comment: You seem to realise a regular expression may be involved (though there are other approaches), what have you tried?

Comment: Note quite a perfect duplicate, but [this C# version could be easily translated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14655023/split-a-string-that-has-white-spaces-unless-they-are-enclosed-within-quotes)?

Comment: iterating over each char and splitting over a space, and if a double quote is encountered skip till next is found. But that is not looking good.

Comment: There is Isaac's answer or `'...'.match(/"[^"]+"|\S+/g)`, which doesn't need *filter* to take out the trash (and handles multiple quoted phrases in the string).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something along the lines of

```js
var str = 'My name is "foo bar" I live in New York';
console.log(str.split(/ |(".*?")/).filter(v=>v));
```

should do the trick

Comment: @RobG noted, fixed

Comment: Might want to use `"[^"]*"` for the quotes part, so that it doesn't jump over any `"` while being more efficient than `".*?"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Isaac

Comment: @Abhijeet you might wanna look into RobG's solution in the comments too

Answer (score 1):

The **regex code** `(?:".*")|\S+` will do exactly that.

`(?:".*")` means any sequence between two mathcing `"` signs
`|` means OR
`\S+` means any sequence of any non-whitespace characters