# Split a comma delimited line being careful not to split on a comma inside block of text

Tags: c#, regex, split

What is the `C#` method to `split` a string with the delimiter as a `','` being careful not to split when the comma is inside a block of text `""`.

So for example, if the string contains

```
""AAC","AAC Holdings, Inc.""
```

the split should return (the `[]` are there to pretend it is an array element of the `string[]` returned by `split`)

```
[AAC] [AAC Holdings, Inc.]
```

not

```
[AAC] [AAC Holdings] [Inc.]
```

Comment: Split can take a combination of characters, so if you use ", (quote mark + comma) instead of just comma it should work

Comment: You're asking for a CSV parser. There are many, but none ship with .NET.

Comment: [Ctl.Data](http://ctl-global.github.io/data.html) is a good CSV parser that'll do this. (shameless plug, it's my library)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43702659/complex-string-split-c-sharp/43702988#43702988

Comment: You might probably want to use `TextFieldParser` for this. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could split with `","` delimiter

```
var description = "\"AAC\",\"AAC Holdings, Inc.\"";
var listText = description.Split(new[] { "\",\"" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (var s in listText)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s.Replace("\"",""));
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

returns

```
AAC
AAC Holdings, Inc.
```

Answer (score 4):

This might probably be best done using `Microsoft.VisualBasic` library (add this in your `reference`), `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` `namespace`, `TextFieldParser` class like this:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;

...

string str = "\"AAC\",\"AAC Holdings, Inc.\"";          

List<string[]> param = new List<string[]>();
string[] words; //add intermediary reference

using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(new StringReader(str))) {
    parser.Delimiters = new string[] { "," }; //the parameter must be comma
    parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true; //VERY IMPORTANT
    while ((words = parser.ReadFields()) != null)
        param.Add(words);
}

foreach (var par in param)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("; ", par));
```

Result:

```
AAC; AAC Holdings, Inc.
```

Note that `TextFieldParser` with `HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true` is specially designed for case as yours.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a free library you can use: [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.net/). I suggest you use a library since it takes care of all these shenanigans for you. Please check out [this](https://www.csvreader.com/csv_benchmarks.php) as well because they load the data to `DataTable` to accomplish what you need and I will also copy the code here in case that link goes dead:

```
string path = @"C:\";
using (OleDbConnection conn =
            new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +
            path + @";Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited"""))
{
    using (OleDbCommand cmd =
        new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM verylarge.csv", conn))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (OleDbDataReader dr =
            cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                int test1 = dr.GetInt32(0);
                int test2 = dr.GetInt32(1);
                int test3 = dr.GetInt32(2);
                int test4 = dr.GetInt32(3);
                int test5 = dr.GetInt32(4);
            }
        }
    }
}
```