# How can I split a string but keep text within quotes together without Regex or Linq

Tags: c#, cosmos

I want to split a string and keep text within quotes so I can properly parse arguments at a command line. However, Regex and Linq are not supported on COSMOS.

I need some way to split a string like the following:

```
This is "a very" important string "doing string things"
```

Into an array with the following contents:

```
{"This", "is", "a very", "important", "string", "doing string things"}
```

The closest I could find that could fix my problem is [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14655185) However, I can't figure out how to convert this to an array because I don't know how to use IEnumerals.

Comment: I'd suggest using a `List<string>` rather than an array then you'd just add to the list where ever it does a yield and return the list at the end.

Comment: If you `.Split('"');`, you already have the parts separated. Now you only need the indexes of the double quotes inside the original string (what Regex.Matches would have already returned as part of the Match).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I firstly split "  then trim and finally with mode split which is not in " " then add them to list string

```
public string[] toArr(string word){
    List<string> result=new List<string>();
    var split1=word.Split('"');
    for(int i=0 ; i<split1.Length ;i++){
        split1[i]=split1[i].Trim();
    }
    for(int i=0;i<split1.Length;i++){
        if(i%2==0){
            var split2=split1[i].Split(' ');
            foreach(var el in split2){
                result.Add(el);
            }
        }
        else{
            result.Add(split1[i]);
        }

    }
    string[] arr=new string[result.Count];
    for(int i=0;i<result.Count;i++){
        arr[i]=result[i];
    }
    return arr;

}
```

Comment: What would happen if there are only 3 quote characters?

Comment: +Louis Go Looks like it assumes the rest is part of the same quote, which is actually what I need.

This answer worked very well. Thank you!